# Trace trap when using strcat()

Tags: c, string, strcat

I'm currently learning to program in C and I can't understand why my terminal outputs: "zsh: trace trap  ./a.out" when running my code.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Hello ";
    char str2[] = "Wolrd!";
    strcat(str, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I type in the terminal:

```
gcc test.c
./a.out
```

Comment: You need to study arrays before you study strings. Notably there is no string class in C and nobody to magically give you more memory when you write out of bounds of an array.

Comment: `str` is an array that can contain exactly 7 chars. You cannot extend it. Don't skip chapters in your learning material. Try `char str[100] = "Hello ";` then it should work. Now `str` can contain up to 100 chars and there will be enough space for `"Hello Wolrd!"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `str` is allocated based on the size of the literal you are initialing it with.  `strcat` presumes you have enough room to concatenate both strings.

change `str[]` to `str[100]` and it would work because you have sufficient space for both strings.  This fixes your problem but you need to understand arrays, memory allocation and read the expectations of the functions like `strcat`.